# onBackPressed is not called when Pressing Back button on Device or from Bottom bar

Tags: java, android, button, navigationbar, back-button

I have a MainActivity as Parent and a SettingsActivity with fragments as Child. Now when i Press on the ActionBar the back Arrow. onBackPressed() gets called normally, but when I Press the back button from the device, onBackPressed is not getting called. How is that button press called? How am I to recognice the back press of the system back Button. I'm working with rockchip tablets, so It is also possible to press back physical on the device. I was hoping the the onBackPressed function called when these buttons are pressed. But they aren't.

What are the necessary steps to do?

[image]

SettingsActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView( R.layout.settings_activity );
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace( R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment() )
            .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );
    }
}
```

BaseActivity:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        lockApp();
        mWebView.loadUrl( getWebViewURL() );
}
```

I hope this paint image I made is sufficent to get the idea what trouble I have right now. I want to onBackPressed function to be called also when pressing the bottom back button or on they device itself but have no clue how I can do that now. Thanks in advance for any help. The Navigation Bar in the SettingsActivity goes into the onBackPressed but not when the bottom buttons are pressed.

Starting the activity fixed it for me, but Im sure this is a bad fix and not the right way, or is it?

SettingsActivity:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

Comment: can you add code that you have did on SettingsActivity for back press event?

Comment: show some code!

Comment: override onBackPress method in settings activity.

Comment: Are you trying to get call of onBackPressed() on Base Activity? Then it is not possible.. You need to override method for back press on SettingsActivity.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi The code I did implement now fixed it, but I feel like this is a really bad Solution.

Comment: I have never called new intent in onBackPress. Check your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!